# The following build commands failed: PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ Pods\ Resources /Users/heliobaob/Library/

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, ionic-framework, cocoapods

Good morning,

I have an application developed on ionic with angular and while I try to run my app with the command "ionic cordova run ios", I get an error that I´ve been trying to solve for days. The error says that some scripts failed during the build process:

**The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ Pods\ Resources /Users/heliobaob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Storecheck-gzoyucsmpcmzqidcbijfleqdddky/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Storecheck/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Storecheck.build/Debug-iphoneos/Storecheck.build/Script-93747F8A261960CA8AAB0BCC.sh (in target 'Storecheck' from project 'Storecheck')
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65**

The script that fails is this:
**#!/bin/sh
"${PODS_ROOT}/Target Support Files/Pods-Storecheck/Pods-Storecheck-resources.sh"**

I really don´t understand what is failing. I already try to remove the ios platform and rebuild it, uninstall cocoapods and reinstalling it, Updating the pods and now I really don´t know what to do, if someone please could help me :(.